# Is this a mistake? (regarding double integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\int_R 6xy^2dydx$ where R = {$(x, y) : 0 ≤ x, y ≤ 1, x -{1\over 2} ≤ y ≤ x +{1\over 2} $}

I made this diagram with Desmos[image]

And then I proceeded to to evaluate the region in red + the region in pink

I got

$$\int_0^{0.5}\int_0^{x+0.5} 6xy^2dydx + \int_{0.5}^{1.5}\int_{x-0.5}^1 6xy^2dydx$$

$$=0.15325+1.35$$

I *know* that the second integral must be incorrect as $1.35$ encompasses more than the pink area (which is $0.5$)

The correct solution in the book is $0.875$, however, that would encompass the entirety of both the red and pink areas as one can see very easily geometrically, so I don't understand how that could be the solution to $6xy^2$.

Can somebody please show me why the method I used is wrong, and explain the correct way to evaluate this integral? Thank you.

*edit: From the answers, I now understand what I did wrong with the diagram and the bounds of the second integral, I am still wondering however how the second integral could be greater than .375 which would be the pink area in the corrected diagram...

Comment: in the second integral, the borders go from $0.5$ to $1$, not $1.5$.

Comment: Can you explain why that is, as the pink area goes until 1.5? Or is my diagram wrong?

Comment: remember $0\le x,y\le 1$, so $x$ goes up to $1$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct integral should be
$$\int_0^{0.5}\int_0^{x+0.5} 6xy^2dydx + \int_{0.5}^{\color{red}1}\int_{x-0.5}^1 6xy^2dydx$$

because $0\le x \le 1$

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little confused visually as the second integral  = .7218 which is still much more the pink area which = .5?

Comment: because your diagram is wrong x must be less than equal 1 but you are drawing your pink shaded area till 1.5

Comment: But if anything that would make the pink region smaller, how can I get something that is bigger than .5? Am I just not understanding how double integration works?